# Setting Numeric scale bar in map composer QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'd like to display the scale bar at a specific cartographic scale.  I'm able to figure out how to display it as a Numeric value but would like to assign it a different value than the one that it's set at.

For example it loads as 1:16260 but I'd like to set it to 1:10000.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to set the scale of the map to 1:10 000, which will then be reflected in the printed numeric scale

[image]